# Многократное повторения SQL запроса

Tags: php, mysql

У меня есть таблица в базе данных. Сильно ли ухудшает производительность, если SQL запрос будет повторяться в цикле скрипта PHP `N` раз?
Например:

```
for($i= 0;i<(любое число);i++)
{
query->(select ID from objects where id=$i);
}
```

Что будет с производительностью, если в таблице будет скажем 100 000, 1 000 000 записей?

Comment: Конечно ухудшит и увеличит нагрузку на БД. Все делай в одном запросе, а в цикле перебирай результат выборки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да производительность упадёт сильно, и вообще такой приём это ужасно. Делайте один комбинированный запрос, или вообще передумывайте архитектуру. Честно говоря, не приходит в голову задачи где может понадобиться такой алгоритм запросов к базе данных.

Comment: Подобной задачи у меня нету. Чисто интерес)

Comment: Раз у вас присутствует интерес к таким вещам, прочитайте про архитектуру СУБД и высоконагружаемые системы. По второму пункту ruhighload.com. И не забудьте под ответом который вас устроил поставить галочку.

Comment: Предположим есть лист объектов - ученики. У них есть свойство - класс, но оно пустое, и идентификатор класса. Нужно  по идентификатору найти класс и привязать его к ученику. Здесь два выхода - или мы формируем запрос в БД, который выберет все нужные классы и потом не явным образом добавляем их к нужным ученикам или же итерируемся по листу учеников и для каждого запрашиваем класс с БД. Как вы думаете в каком случае код будет более консервативный? Вот вам один из вариантов. ПС ничего страшного в таком подходе нету, просто в таком виде нету смысла в нем.